# Two clicks needed on jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm doing some jQuery validation on a form that uses a custom method on a text field (`uniqueURL`, shown below).  All of this works fine (validation success and failure) as long as the user enters a value into the text field and then clicks out of the field before clicking the Submit button.  If, instead, he enters text into the field and then immediately clicks on the Submit button, the validation function runs again and the Submit button goes into its "clicked" appearance (via twitter bootstrap), but the form is not submitted.  However, a second click on Submit successfully submits the form.

There's no shortage of posts here and elsewhere asking two-click questions, but I haven't been able to adapt any of their suggestions to this situation.  Any advice out there?  Thanks!

```
$.validator.addMethod('uniqueURL',
                        function (value) {
                            var validator = this;
                            var theData = { url: $('#edit-link').attr('value'), parent_nid: 123 };
                            var theResult;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: 'http://www.example.com/doc-url-check', 
                                data: theData,
                                success: function(response) {
                                            var the_result = response[0];
                                            switch (the_result) {
                                                case 0: // empty
                                                case -1: // not a url
                                                case -2: // already in use
                                                    $.validator.messages.uniqueURL = response[1];
                                                    theResult = false;
                                                    break;
                                                default:
                                                    theResult = true;
                                                    break;
                                                };
                                            }, 
                                dataType: 'json',
                                async: false
                            });
                            return theResult;
                            },
                        'We\'re having trouble checking on this link: Please try again later.');

$('form#edit_document').validate({
        rules: {
                'files[field_local_file_private]': { required: true, extension: 'doc|xls|txt' },
                link: { required: false, uniqueURL: true } 
               },
        messages: {
            title: 'What\'s the title of this document?',
            doc_type: 'Are you storing a document or adding a link to a webpage?',
            'files[field_local_file_private]': 'Please select one of the following types of files: doc, xls, or txt',
            },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            switch (element.attr('name')) {
                case 'title':
                    error.insertAfter('.form-item-title > label');
                    break;
                case 'doc_type':
                    error.insertAfter('.control-group.form-item-doc-type > label');
                    break;
                case 'files[field_local_file_private]':
                    error.insertAfter('#edit-field-local-file-private');
                    break;
                case 'link':
                    error.insertAfter('#edit-link');
                    break;
                 }
            },
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) { 
            $('form#edit_document a.btn-primary').button('reset'); // reset the data-loading-text bit if validation failed
            $('#modal_edit_document').css('cursor', 'auto');
            },
});
```

html (hand-indented; there may be one (more?) extra closing div in here, but it renders correctly); the hidden vars are from Drupal's form process:

```
<form id="edit_document" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/handle-add-document" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <h3>Add a document</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="vr_overlay_form">
            <div class="control-group form-type-textfield form-item-title form-item">
                <label class="control-label" for="edit-title">Title </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" maxlength="128" size="60" value="" name="title" id="edit-title" class="required form-text valid" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="vr_document_doc_type_widget span5">
                <div id="edit-doc-type" class="control-group form-type-radios form-item-doc-type">
                    <label class="control-label">What kind of document is this?</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div id="doc-type-stored" class="row doc_type_element">
                            <div class="doc_type_label">
                                <div class="form-type-radio form-item-doc-type form-item">
                                    <label for="edit-doc-type-stored" class="option radio"> 
                                        <input type="radio" value="stored" name="doc_type" id="edit-doc-type-stored" class="required form-radio">Stored
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="doc_type_action">
                            <div id="edit-field-local-file-private-ajax-wrapper">
                                <div class="control-group form-type-managed-file form-item-field-local-file-private form-disabled form-item">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="form-managed-file" id="edit-field-local-file-private">
                                    <input type="file" class="form-file" size="22" name="files[field_local_file_private]" id="edit-field-local-file-private-upload" disabled="disabled" style="opacity: 1;">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="field_local_file_private[fid]" disabled="disabled" style="opacity: 1;">
                                </div>
                                <p class="help-block" style="opacity: 1;">message</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="doc-type-link" class="row doc_type_element">
                <div class="doc_type_label">
                    <div class="form-type-radio form-item-doc-type form-item">
                        <label for="edit-doc-type-link" class="option radio"> 
                            <input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="link" name="doc_type" id="edit-doc-type-link">Link
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="doc_type_action">
                    <div class="control-group form-type-textfield form-item-link form-disabled form-item">
                        <div class="controls"> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-text required valid" maxlength="128" size="60" value="" name="link" id="edit-link" autocomplete="off">
                            <p class="help-block" style="opacity: 0.5;">message</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> /* extra, not needed? */

    <div class="control-group form-type-textarea form-item-doc-notes form-item">
        <label class="control-label" for="edit-doc-notes">Notes (optional) </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable"><textarea class="form-textarea" rows="5" cols="60" name="doc_notes" id="edit-doc-notes"></textarea></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="269" name="parent_nid">
    <input type="hidden" value="vr_project" name="parent_type">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="doc_nid">
    <input type="hidden" value="21" name="account_uid">
    <input type="hidden" value="project-documents" name="return_to">
    <input type="hidden" value="form-eSJkxfwxjj4FWITiqDz6re-mbjQFHDi5waC5XAvm05I" name="form_build_id">
    <input type="hidden" value="pTO81aOnM29HpxAAOvF_EBF1ERTLzdjvmAprg7MDyOM" name="form_token">
    <input type="hidden" value="vr_document_add_form" name="form_id">
    </div></div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a data_dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary saver" href="#" onclick="modal_submit('edit_document')">Save</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think something must be wrong with your custom method or server-side code.  Because, right now, as written, your validation rules are evaluated on every key up, on focus out, and upon submit.  The only difference as per your description is the user clicking outside of the field (on focus out event) before clicking submit.  It's unclear, from what you've shown, how this one extra evaluation is preventing your issue from occurring.

Comment: If the server-side code and the custom method are written properly, a single evaluation (on submit), should be enough for it to work without two clicks.  For troubleshooting, you can disable `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` by setting them to `false`. Just remember to _remove them_ when you want the functionality activated, because setting them to `true` is not valid as per docs.

Comment: Thanks very much for the notes.  It's indeed a puzzle; I'll continue to poke at it and see if I can figure out what's going on.  (I'm about to take off for a couple of weeks of travel, so it might be awhile...)